# Convert Web App (coded in Google Script) to Offline

Tags: google-apps-script, offline, google-drive-api

I have written a Drive App.
My current code in Server Side: code.gs (GScript & DriveAPI) + index.html (with html & JScript). The html is called from code.gs by doGet(), and then callback by google.script.run.

I and want to further make it available in offline mode too. I have read through many documents in Google about offline mode. However, Google hasn't mentioned if Web App coded in Google Script can be for Offline mode or not. I know the zip for uploading need to include, not only icon and modified manifest.json, but also the code and html. My questions are:

1.code.gs: Should I just directly copy it to a local code.js and include it into upload.zip?

2.index.html: Just need to add back  etc. tags?

Any special conversion do I need to care?

Comment: .gs code is included in the Apps Script Project file.  I wouldn't think you would need to somehow separate out the .gs and html files from the Apps Script file.

Comment: By searching ID, the installed folder contains just the initial uploaded manifest.json and icon. Google Apps Script hasn't re-packaged them with my code.gs and index.html automatically. I am afraid I need to re-write the project as a normal project. If in that case, I worry that I can no longer take direct advantage of using Javascript in Server as in Google Script, unless I take time to investigate node.js.

Comment: Apps Script does **not** work offline.

Comment: Hi Henrique, thanks for your confirmation, which is important. But since so many people are using PHP, Java, JScript to write offline app in Chrome Store, I can't totally understand your scope of "not work".

Originally I just want to know should I specially care when converting from Google Script to local JScript, and I suppose Chrome has embedded Google's Classes & library inside (like DriveApp.*). Is my understanding incorrect? None of the packaged app can access offline google drive?

Comment: Impossible to do so. .gs runs server side and offline has no access to the server. No access to offline drive either, the google libraries work only online. Would be cool thou.

Comment: If it is the case, it is too pity. :(